# Install4j Error instantiating Actions

Tags: install4j

I am changing the installer on an application and in the install4j IDE I am getting the error "Error instantiating (class-path-to-action)". I don't know what is causing the error or what to do to fix it.

This is the second time I have come across this while using the install4j IDE, although the first time the error disappeared once I had built the project and closed eclipse.

This time round I have tried opening up the install4j file right after a restart and I am getting the same error, with no luck in getting rid of it.

Can someone enlighten me on what could be causing this, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information in the file %TEMP%\install4j_error.log about the exception. Probably the class path configured on the Installer->Custom code & Resources is not correct.